# Amazon web service api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using amazon web service to extract product information. It was working fine, however it is providing the following output now:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Request denied by pfSense proxy: 403 Forbidden</h3>
        <b> Reason: </b>
        <hr size="1" noshade>
        <b> Client address: </b> 192.168.0.46
        <br>
        <b> Client name:    </b> 192.168.0.46
        <br>
        <b> Client group:   </b> default
        <br>
        <b> Target group:   </b> Bloack_Sites
        <br>
        <b> URL:            </b> http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        <br>
        <hr size="1" noshade>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a local issue

Comment: can you check if client can ping or can access the AWS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be running on a corporate network that is **sending web traffic through a proxy** (`pfSense proxy`).

The error is showing a **private IP address** (`192.168.0.46`), which means the request never made it to the Internet.

You should chat with your network administrators and determine why it is listed in a group called `Bloack_Sites` (presumably, 'Blocked sites'?).

Comment: Thanks John. The access was blocked. Problem has been solved now. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the address is address:  192.168.0.46
and the client name is address:  192.168.0.46
Then the target group is undefined: Bloack_Sites not recognized.
Target group:                     Block_Sites

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).